# Which permissions are required to edit Organization policies on folder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to use terraform resource `google_folder_organization_policy` and I only have this error:
`Error: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden`

**So I'm not sure which permissions I'm missing.**

Folder level permissions of SA's are:
`Project IAM Admin`, `Organisation Administrator`, `Folder Admin`, and others but rather not related.

example code:

```
resource "google_folder_organization_policy" "disable_service_account_creation" {
  folder = "1234567890"
  constraint = "iam.disableServiceAccountCreation"

  restore_policy {
    default = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account must be "Organization Policy Administrator".

But, take care of this trick: You have to grant the "Organization Policy Administrator" role at the organisation level. Of course, without any other permissions on the organization itself. And then grant the folder admin role to the SA to allow access to that folder level in the hierarchy

The engineering team is working on a feature named Authority Delegation, to avoid the grant at the top level, and only at the folder/project level. No ETA for now, don't expect it by the end of the year.

Comment: Thanks for additional info regarding this useful feature. It will be warmly welcomed ;)